# Decrease computation time of module

Tags: scoping, summation, performance-tuning

I need to compute the exponential of a matrix (in this case`R`) by the summation method where `R` is a square matrix with symbolic entries and `n` is the number of summation terms. I've written a function, which works as intended, but is quite slow - however faster than `MatrixExp[]`. Is there a way to increase the computational efficiency (decrease computational time) of the below function?
Thanks in advance!

```
Qfun[n0_, R0_] :=
 Module[{n = n0, R = R0},
  temp = IdentityMatrix[Length[R]];
  sumR = IdentityMatrix[Length[R]];

  For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
   temp = temp.R;
   sumR = sumR + ((t^k)/Factorial[k]) temp;
   ];
  ]
```

Comment: Your `Module` is quite a mess. It would be helpful if you can add a simple example to your question, which shows how you use your function and that it is slower than `MatrixExp`. Additionally, are there any restrictions to the parameters? For instance seems `n0 > Length[R0]` useless, right?

Comment: If you ask, why your `Module` is a mess: you copy the input parameter `n0` and `R0` although you don't have to because you never assign them any new values. On the other hand, you don't localise your *local* variables `temp`, `sumR`, `k` and `t` and use global variables instead. They should go into the `Module`.

Comment: I don't believe I understand, can you explain how local variables will decreased computation speed? How can I make my `Module` less messy?

Comment: T is undefined.